# Android launchType: always call onCreate

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am a little confused concerning Android launch types. How can I achieve the following:

1. There should be at most one instance of my activity in the history stack, i.e. I don't want to navigate back trough several instances of the same activity.
2. Whenever I call the activity via intent, `onCreate()` should be called.

As I understand the activity lifecycle, the latter means that the activity has to be recreated. But how? [image]

Comment: I am not aware that you can get what you want via `android:launchType`. Specifically, Android will re-use an existing running instance of your activity, if there is one, and in that case you will be called with `onNewIntent()` rather than `onCreate()`. Is there a specific reason why you feel that `onCreate()` is essential?

Comment: Just because of migration costs, nothing more :-)